# Error connected to factor var when using logistic model to predict

Tags: r, error-handling, logistic-regression

Forgive me if my title is unclear, but I couldn't think a very clear way to summarize what I'm after.

I'm working with the Titanic dataset to learn logistic regression. The idea is to develop a model to predict survival. The data includes passenger `Age`. Using that attribute, I factored `Age` like

```
Age_labels <- c('0-10', '11-17', '18-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79')

train_data$AgeGroup <- cut(train_data$Age, c(0, 11, 18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), include.highest=TRUE, labels= Age_labels)
```

Model completed, I'm ready to use it to predict survival on the test data--but I get an error when I try

```
test_data_predictions <- predict(my_model, newdata = test_data, type = "response")
```

Here's the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
> xlev = object$xlevels) :    factor AgeGroup has new levels 60-69,
> 70-79

Why? It *seems* to mean the problem is because the test data includes passengers in the 60-69 and 70-79 AgeGroup (whereas train data did not include passengers in those age ranges). Or does the error actually mean something else?

Obviously I want to use this model to predict the survival of *any* passenger, regardless of age.

Here is a potential clue: str() tells me that `AgeGroup` in my `test_data` is a factor w /8 levels, whereas in `train_data` it's a factor w /6 levels. Also, there are no `NA`s in either train_data or test_data.

How do I correct the error so I can move on to actual predictions? Thanks

Note: haven't included data as this question does not seem to require reproducibility to answer

**UPDATE**

Per suggestion by @sjp, I went back and treated `AgeGroup` as continuous variable (as numeric). Doing so has adverse effects: AIC goes up, binnedplot of residuals now looks rather poor (too many outside of bin), and Hosmer-Lemeshow now says "Summary: model does not fit well". So, passing `AgeGroup` as numeric *does* make it possible for me to use model to make predictions on test data, but I worry the price is too high.

Comment: Any easy solution here would just be to treat age as a continuous variable. Do you have access to the non-binned data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @sjp. But two things: (1) the model's AIC changes when I run with `AgeGroup` as numeric vs as factor (lower AIC as factor), and (2) I'd also like to understand the error better. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to select your training set in a balanced/stratified way, so that all of the factor levels from the data set are represented in the training set and the testing set. There are ways to do this in R but I haven't dug them up yet.

Comment: That's sensible, @BenBolker. I should've made clear in my question that I tried to accomplish that by running `Age_labels <- c('0-10', '11-17', '18-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79')

test_data$AgeGroup <- cut(test_data$Age, c(0, 11, 18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), include.highest=TRUE, labels= Age_labels)` for test_data, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Because there are age groups present in the test set that are in the training set (due to random sampling of small categories), R can't make predictions for those test cases. You can use `caret::createDataPartition(age_group)` to create a train/test split that is balanced on the age-group variable (and hence is not missing any categories). The help page (`?createDataPartition`) warns you that "for ... very small class sizes (<= 3) the classes may not show up in both the training and test data", but it seems to work OK here (the smallest group has n=6).

### replicate the problem

```r
tt <- transform(carData::TitanicSurvival,
                age_group = cut(age,
                               breaks = c(0, 11, 18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80))
                )
set.seed(101)
## allocate a small fraction (10%) to the training set to make 
##   it easier to get missing classes in the training set
split1 <- sample(c("train", "test"),
                 size = nrow(tt),
                 replace = TRUE,
                 prob = c(0.1, 0.9))
m1 <- glm(survived ~ age_group, family = binomial,
          data = tt[split1 == "train", ])
try(predict(m1, newdata = tt[split1 == "test",]))
```

this gives

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
> factor age_group has new levels (70,80]

as in the original example.

### balanced sample

```r
library(caret)
set.seed(101)
w <- createDataPartition(tt$age_group, p = 0.1)$Resample1
table(tt$age_group[w])
table(tt$age_group[-w])
m2 <- glm(survived ~ age_group, family = binomial, data = tt[w,])
predict(m2, newdata = tt[-w,])
```

This works OK. Using `table(tt$age_group[w])` and `table(tt$age_group[-w])` confirms that every age class is present in both the training and the test set, although it doesn't cause any problems if classes are missing from the *test set* only ...